# I've transferred ownership of my token to my crowdsale, how do I transfer it back?

Tags: solidity, wallet-transfer

I've seen 2 solutions here and they worked for others but they aren't working for me. I have no problem transferring ownership to the crowdsale, but how do I code it to be able to transfer the ownership of the token back to my main account?

I've created a function for it, and it gives me no errors, it even executes with no problem, but it never changes the ownership. Here's the partial code of my crowdsale:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;



/**
 * @title Owned
 * @dev The Owned contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
contract Owned {
  address public owner;



  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
  event TokenOwnershipTransferred(address indexed _newOwner, address indexed _previousOwner);


  /**
   * @dev The Owned constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
   * account.
   */
  function Owned() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
}


    function transferTokenOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(_newOwner != address(0));
     emit TokenOwnershipTransferred(owner, _newOwner);
     owner = _newOwner;

}
}

interface token {
    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) external;

}


library SafeMath {

  /**
  * @dev Multiplies two numbers, throws on overflow.
  */
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Integer division of two numbers, truncating the quotient.
  */
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Subtracts two numbers, throws on overflow (i.e. if subtrahend is greater than minuend).
  */
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Adds two numbers, throws on overflow.
  */
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

contract FCCCrowdsale is Owned{
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address public beneficiary;
    uint256 public fundingGoal;
    uint256 public amountRaised;
    uint256 public openingTime;
    uint256 public closingTime;
    uint256 public initialRate;
    uint256 public finalRate;
    token public tokenReward;


    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

      event Closed();
```

Comment: Can you give more details as to how you're trying to call the function to transfer ownership back? Also im not sure why you have two different transfer ownership functions? There's no clear reason as to why you chose those two, and I suspect that's probably why you're running into an issue, but without more information as to how you're passing hte ownership off initially, and how you're trying to pass it back its not possible to find a solution.

Comment: 1 function serves the purpose of transferring the ownership of the crowdsale contract and the 2nd to transfer the ownership of the actual token. I have no intention of ever transferring ownership of the crowdsale, but I'm not sure why that would create issues in trying to transfer the token itself. I could try it with just one, but the crowdsale indeed needs to be owned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @btc4cash said, you can not, unless you write the crowd-sale contract in such a manner that it can transfer ownership back.

Check out this sample code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Token{
    address public owner;

    function transferOwnerShip(address _newOwner) public {
        require (msg.sender == owner);
        owner = _newOwner;
    }

    function Token() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}


contract Crowdsale{
    Token tokenContract;
    address crowdsaleOwner;

    function Crowdsale(address _tokenAddress) public {
      tokenContract = Token(_tokenAddress);
      crowdsaleOwner = msg.sender;
    }


    function transferOwnerShipBack(address _newOwner) public {
        require(msg.sender == crowdsaleOwner);
        tokenContract.transferOwnerShip(_newOwner);
    }
}
```

You can execute `transferOwnerShipBack` method of crowdsale contract to transfer ownership to a new user.

**PS:** This was just for the demo purpose. Test before use in production.

**Edit 1: Explanation on the Code works**
Since it is very clear that smart contracts can only execute what their code allows. SO if you need to transfer ownership to your crowdsale contract, the crowdsale contract **must** have  a method to transfer ownership back. The above code sample does exactly the same.

Let me make this very clear, there are 2 contracts **Token** and **Crowdsale** and both needs to be deployed separately.

- Open Remix Compiler (or choose other methods if you want)
- Paste the above code into the editor
- There you have  5 accounts (if using Javascript VM). Let's call accounts with Acc1, Acc2 ...
- Deploy **Token** contract from Acc1.
- Copy Token contract address and pass this as constructor argument while deploying `Crowdsale contract`. Deploy Crowdsale contract from Acc2.
- Call transferOwnership method of Token Contact from Acc1 and transfer Ownership to `Crowdsale Contract`.
- Now you can check the owner of `Token contract` is the Crowdsale Contract.
- Now if you need to transfer back the ownership of Token COntract to Acc1. JUst call `transferOwnershipBack` of Crowdsale Contract from Acc2, passing Acc1 as an argument.

I have taken an example of multiple accounts just to show that both contracts are independent can will behave even if have different owners. You can do all the same with a single account as well if you don't want to complicate things.

Comment: Thanks Prashant, I'm going to try this. The other solution said to do pretty much the same thing but wasn't as comprehensive as your example. I'll let you know how it works out!

Comment: OK so I tried that, and it's giving me an TypeError: Member "transferOwnership" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Token 
tokenContract.transferOwnership. 

I'm going to try something else. I think it may have to do with the @param comments.

Comment: Got rid of the errors, deployed it and now it's giving me an always failing transaction or gas limit too high. I'm stumped.

Comment: This is not a valid issue. Obly thing that change on the transfer ownership back function is that the modifier onlyOwner was remplaced by requiring the sender been the contract owner, which is the SAME. Very weak answer.

Comment: Yeah, the new function was exactly the same. This is why it looped and wouldn't execute. I figured that out and was going to come back and comment on it once I got things sorted.

Comment: @btc4cash Yes I didn't add onlyOnwer modifier instead replace it with require statement. Because as I mentioned this was a demo code, so writing a modifier will add more lines of code. This was just to make things simpler. BTW can you point out why you find the answer week?

Comment: Because the function to transfer back is exactly doing the same than original, modifier is only replaced by the require statement which do the same. If you set a new owner, only the new owner can revert that. Its not the OP goal.

Comment: If op set the contract itself as new owner, he will not be able to revert that.

Comment: And if he set X as new owner, only X can revert back.

Comment: Man, the `transferOwnerShip` function is put into Token contract and `transferOwnerShipBack` is in crowdsale contract. Both may or may not have same user. So if ownership  is transferred to crowdsale, the crowdsale owner can transfer it back.

Comment: You didn't get the concept. It's not the same function written twice. Ig you pay little attention, you'll see there are 2 contracts, that need to deployed separately. And you only have to make external call to Token Contract in order to transfer ownership back.

Comment: Let's not argue. Prashant, I assumed you meant the code should go into each contract, wasn't sure though and I'm not sure I coded it properly as you meant it. 

Doing that now however leads me to another question, as for the Crowdsale contract, should I import the token file? As it stands, "Token tokenContract;" throws an error as being unidentified.

Comment: Yes, you may include the token contract, or even the Token contract interface will do. Just declare the methods and don't write the implementation in crowd safe.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Threw all types of errors. Then after some tweaking, I got it to deploy and execute but it kept transferring the ownership right back to the crowdsale contract.

Comment: Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Updated. See if this resolves your query.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience Prashant. I'm not sure why this is not working for me. The problem I'm having is the 'tokenContract.transferOwnerShip(_newOwner);' always throws an error for me. "Member "transferOwnership" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract token. 

I tried another way by creating an event. No errors, and I'm able to execute the function it just refuses to transfer the ownership back. Here is the full code so you can maybe see what I'm doing wrong. [link](https://github.com/shyheim103/IndygoArt/blob/master/Test/IndygoCrowdsale3.sol)

Comment: You are using `token` interface to represent your token contract.So the interface must have the signature of all the methods you want to use. Just add `function transferOwnership(address) external;` line in `interface token` and this should work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75323/discussion-between-shyheim103-and-prashant-prabhakar-singh).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot.

Edit:

As I said, what I do is the ICO create the token in constructor, and constructor of the token itself accept the ICO address as the parameter. This way you have an owner AND the ICO address in the token.

Actual code I see is only owner can transfer the ownership, and not to himself. So once transfered, only the new owner can transfer the ownership back because of the onlyOwner modifier.

If there was not this modifier, anyone could transfer ownership which is obliviously not a good idea :)

Comment: Exactly, I definitely don't want that. But there are people who have pulled this off, but for some reason their string doesn't work. Here is a link to a solution, but I can't see what i'm doing wrong. :https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34184/transfer-ownership-of-a-token-contract

Comment: I just checked link its a non sense as well. Contract cannot call by itself a function someone need to call it. So even giving the ownership to the contract itself will still have the issue than anyone would be able to transfer back the owner ship to pevious owner anytime or worst to themself.

Comment: Exactly. I saw one instance where someone said it worked. However, I can't find that thread anymore but the code was very similar if not exact. I have managed twice now, coding it different ways to get it to actually execute the function, it just doesn't give the ownership to the new address, the crowdsale keeps giving the ownership back to itself. And it needs to be an "onlyOwner" function, otherwise my sale/token would be doomed. 

I may just have to look at this another way and just do a fixed sale and not a mintable one.

Comment: If you find send me :) what I do publish ICO, the contrcutor of it create the token and suppliy owner AND ICO address, this way ICO can mint token. :)

Comment: I have it setup that way, but I still want control over the tokens after the fact. Let's say if there is some investigation and the government requests my help of an account they're tracing, I can freeze it. Or (because I'm creating a marketplace), let's say a seller sends a buyer a product not as described; but they already cashed out their token. I could still reimburse the buyer buy minting new tokens and freeze the seller's account indefinitely.

Comment: Then why you want to give owner ship? Why you just don't use one account as owner?

Comment: I can't because both the token contract and the crowdsale contract need ownership. The crowdsale needs it to mint tokens.

Comment: As I said, what I do is the ICO create the token in constructor, and constructor of the token itself accept the ICO address as the parameter. This way you have an owner AND the ICO address in the token :)

Comment: hilarious! I like the way you think. It makes me wonder why anyone would do it any other way? I had to really think about what you were saying but yeah, I'll just create the coin within the crowdsale and boom, I have ownership of everything without the need to transfer anything! Once the timed crowdsale is over that function becomes deprecated. Thanks! Will try it and let you know how it works out. Should work fine though.

Comment: Yes and when crowdsale is done, people can still interact with the token without the corwdsale :)

Comment: Ran into a problem with this method. It's the same situation as before. In order to mint tokens, this contract needs ownership of itself. So I still have to transfer ownership from the account that created this contract to this contract. So after the sale, I can't do anything. This is actually worse off than before because I could at least send refunds. This just locks and freezes everything, so I still need to figure out how to transfer ownership back.